# Can't connect to host drive from Hyper-V VM when using external switch

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 Pro machine (Creators Edition, build 1703) with Hyper-V installed, and a Win 10 Pro VM (same build). Everything seemed to be working fine at first, when the VM was using an internal virtual switch. I changed that to an external switch hooked up to my Wifi, because I needed Internet connectivity. But now I can't access shared folders on the host.

I have network discovery and file/printer sharing enabled on both the host and VM, for all network types (private, domain, public):

[image]

In Explorer on the VM, I can see the host machine show up under the Network tree. But trying to access anything on there results in an error.

[image]

I do have a shared folder on the host drive D, which I've managed to access before.

More information: I'm working from home on a domain-joined PC. The IP addresses for the host and VM are 192.168.0.3 and 192.168.0.2 respectively. The subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 for both.

The admin policy won't let me disable the firewall on the host, however I can access a shared folder on the VM from the host (it's the other way around that's causing the problem). Ping works both ways. A screenshot of firewall rules that seem relevant:

[image]

Comment: A similar issue in windows 7 and Xp occurred the same see if any of the answers [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-network-error-code-0x80070035-windows/84791143-b70a-4ec2-b700-98df657fe45c) will help you.

Comment: What is your IP configuration for the machines? Can you access them via IP instead of computer name?

Comment: @Twisty The machines are talking to each other via IPV6. I can ping the host from the VM, and the VM from the host, using both the computer name and the IP address.

Comment: Then next step is to disable firewalls/security software (for testing only!). Make sure both machines are in the private network profile too.

Comment: @Twisty I disabled the firewall on the VM, but it had no effect. I can't disable the firewall on the host, the admin policy doesn't allow it.

Comment: @HongOoi That's no good. Can you access a shared folder on the VM from the host? Try changing the option on the host for HomeGroup connections to **Use user accounts...**

Comment: I've already set the Homegroup to use user accounts. There's no Homegroup anyway. I _can_ access a shared VM folder from the host though.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that this machine is joined to the corporate network? Do I have to join the VM as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem (or maybe it's more of a workaround) by adding an internal switch to the VM, to go with the external one. After doing that, I could access my folder.

The caveat is that I have to use an IP address (169.254.xxx.yyy) instead of the computer name to refer to the host, but that's good enough for now.